# Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed - Laravel caching with Datatable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis, predis

```
if (!Cache::store('file')->has('channel')) {
        $products = Channel::select('*');
        Cache::store('redis')->put('channel', $products, 86400);
}
$products = Cache::store('redis')->get('channel', []);

return DataTables::eloquent($products)
      ->addIndexColumn()
      ->make(true);
```

This throws me "Serialization of 'PDO' is not allowed", if i am trying

```
if (!Cache::store('file')->has('channel')) {
        $products = Channel::select('*')->get();
        Cache::store('redis')->put('channel', $products, 86400);
}
$products = Cache::store('redis')->get('channel', []);

return DataTables::eloquent($products)
      ->addIndexColumn()
      ->make(true);
```

then datatables throws error of Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getQuery does not exist

Anyone have solution for these?

Comment: Use the second option, as you can't serialize a query object. Don't use the `eloquent()` method if you're not passing an Eloquent collection. Just use `of()` and let `Datatables` class figure out what you're passing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `::of()` instead of `::eloquent()`.